# Computing grouped medians in DolphinDB

Tags: sql, distributed-computing, median, dolphindb

I have a DFS table in DolphinDB. I tried to run a query that would compute grouped medians on this table. But it just threw an exception.

```
select median(col1) from t group by col2
```

> The aggregated function in column med(v1) doesn't have a map-reduce implementation and can't be applied to a partitioned or distributed table.

Seems to me that DolphinDB does not support distributed median algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The aggregated function `median` differs from `avgerage` in that it can't be solved by map-reduce. So we have to pull the data and then apply the median function to each group.

DolphinDB's repartition mechanism make such work much easier.

```
ds = repartitionDS(<select first(col2) as col2, median(col1) as col1 from t>,`col2, VALUE)
mr(ds, x->x,,unionAll{false})
```